# AMI 7838? (identify this part)

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

Help appreciated identifying part and finding datasheet.

Top reads:

AMI 7838

S2114L2CC (might be a 5 not an S)

Bottom reads:

7835A1

1560

KOREA

18 pin ceramic DIP, gold plated? pins

[image: top side]

[image: bottom side]

Comment: Thats a 2114 SRAM. 1024x4 bits.

Comment: all that gold .... muuahhhaaahhhaaa

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As *Janka* said in comments, this is a **2114 SRAM** (more specifically, 2114L low-power version). The clues are:

- `2114` (`2114L`) in the part number
- 18-pin DIP package (I used 2114 devices in that 18-pin ceramic DIP package shown in the photo, as well as plastic DIP).
- the date code of `7838` (YYWW format) on the top, matches the era of the 2114 (late 1970s to early 1980s)

The `AMI` mark in the part number isn't American Megatrends Inc. (the BIOS manufacturer often referred to as "AMI"), as they aren't a semiconductor manufacturer. <strike>However, I haven't found definitive evidence which company used that mark - I thought it might have been AMI Semiconductors (later taken over by ON Semi) but I'm not sure.</strike> [Found more details about the manufacturer - yes, it's the predecessor to AMI Semiconductors - see update below.]

Example 2114 SRAM datasheets from other manufacturers:

- [Fairchild 2114L datasheet](https://www.princeton.edu/~mae412/HANDOUTS/Datasheets/2114.pdf)
- [NEC uPD2114L datasheet](https://www.silicon-ark.co.uk/datasheets/uPD2114l-datasheet-nec.pdf)

---

Update: Found the manufacturer - [American Microsystems Inc. (AMI)](http://www.antiquetech.com/?page_id=817) who were [later renamed AMI Semiconductors and then bought by ON Semi](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/american_microsystems).

- They used an `S` prefix before their part number, as seen in the `S2114L2CC` part number.
- They had a packaging facility (to mount the silicon dies into the DIP packages) in Korea, which matches the marking in the photo.
- I found the datasheet for that device - but it's in a 20.6 MB PDF file:
  [American Microsystems Inc. (AMI) MOS Products Catalogue, Winter 1979](https://archive.org/download/bitsavers_amidataBoos_21647406/1979_AMI_MOS_Products.pdf)

  See page 35 in the PDF file (marked page number "2.4") which includes the `S2114L-2` which I suspect is correct for that device (the `-2` indicates a speed rating).

  For different formats of that scanned AMI data book, [see the archive.org page here](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_amidataBoos_21647406).